# SQL Server update caused Datediff to not work

Tags: sql-server, datediff

I know there were several articles about this topic already and I went through them but I still am not able to get this to run properly. I also used `DATEDIFF_BIG`, but then I get this error:

> DATEDIFF_BIG is not a recognized built-in function name.

This used to be able to run but I think there was a SQL server update and now all of the TAT queries are breaking.

```
SELECT
    MSTR.FIRST_OF_MTH AS [MONTH],
    COALESCE(R.[AREA],T.[AREA]) AS [AREA],
    COALESCE(R.NUM_REQUESTS,0) AS NUM_REQUESTS,
    COALESCE(R.DURATION_REQ,0) AS DURATION_REQ,
    COALESCE(T.NUM_TRANS,0) AS NUM_TRANS,
    COALESCE(T.DURATION_TRANS,0) AS DURATION_TRANS
FROM
        (
        SELECT FIRST_OF_MTH
        FROM [EPICDW].[DBO].[DATE_EXT]
        WHERE (YEAR([DATE_EXT].[THEDATE]) BETWEEN YEAR(GETDATE()) - 1 AND YEAR(GETDATE()))
        GROUP BY FIRST_OF_MTH
        ) MSTR
LEFT JOIN 
        (
        --transactions
        SELECT
                DATEADD(month, DATEDIFF(month, 0, [CLOSE_DT]), 0) AS [MONTH],
                [TEAM] AS AREA,
                SUM(1) AS NUM_TRANS,
                SUM(B.[Calendar_Duration]) AS DURATION_TRANS
        FROM [dbo].[v_tab_config_bl_trans_comb]
        CROSS APPLY fn_Ben_Ops_Turnaround ([OPEN_DT], [CLOSE_DT]) B
        WHERE Year([CLOSE_DT]) BETWEEN YEAR(GETDATE()) - 1 AND YEAR(GETDATE())
        GROUP BY
                DATEADD(month, DATEDIFF(month, 0, [CLOSE_DT]), 0),
                [TEAM]
        ) T
        ON MSTR.FIRST_OF_MTH = T.[MONTH]
LEFT JOIN 
        (
        --requests
        SELECT 
                DATEADD(month, DATEDIFF(month, 0, [CLOSED_DT]), 0) AS [MONTH],
                TEAM AS AREA,
                SUM(1) AS NUM_REQUESTS,
                SUM([DUR_CAL]) AS DURATION_REQ
          FROM [dbo].[v_tab_config_requests]
          WHERE year([CLOSED_DT]) BETWEEN YEAR(GETDATE()) - 1 AND YEAR(GETDATE())
        GROUP BY DATEADD(month, DATEDIFF(month, 0, [CLOSED_DT]), 0),        TEAM
        ) R
ON MSTR.FIRST_OF_MTH = R.[MONTH]
AND T.AREA = R.AREA
```

Comment: If datediff_big generates an error, that begs the question of what version/edition of sql server you are using. Ignoring that red herring, wWhat exactly does "not able to get this to run properly" mean? How do you know? If it generates an error - post it, all of it.

Comment: It used to run and now it doesn't. Something happened and the only thing I can think of was the server update we had in nov. Now slowly all of the TAT queries that we have are breaking "not running". Like I tried several different methods DATEADD(month, Convert(BIGINT, DATEDIFF(month, 0, [CLOSE_DT])), 0) AS [MONTH]. That didnt work either.

Comment: @Sam - you will need to provide the exact error - otherwise there is nothing to go on. Just saying it no longer runs is not sufficient unless we had your database to experiment with.

Comment: The datediff function resulted in an overflow. The number of dateparts separating two date/time instances is too large. Try to use datediff with a less precise datepart.

Comment: So i was researching and some of the information came up regarding view. Two of the tables are from view. How do I go about verifying if the definition is correct or test to see if the view is causing the error.

Comment: Look at the definition of the Views - look for any use of date related functions in the views as that may be where the error is arising - try doing ```SELECT * FROM [view_name]``` to verify if any errors originate there